# php/apache: allow larger max_execution_time for a CRON job?

Tags: php, apache

I want run a php script weekly using a cron job, however the script may take a few minutes or more.

**Is there any way i can allow a greater `max_execution_time` just for this script?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP command line: max_execution_time and memory_limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181459/php-command-line-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try these answers:

- [How do you get a Cronjob executing a PHP script to run longer than 30 seconds.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693857/how-do-you-get-a-cronjob-executing-a-php-script-to-run-longer-than-30-seconds)
- [PHP command line: max_execution_time and memory_limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181459/php-command-line-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit)

But of course, using `ini_set("max_execution_time",60)` as the first php line in your job's script should do the trick.

Regards, Daniel

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to set a higher max_execution_time if you use PHP CLI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Comment: Interesting but can you include in your answer how to run the file as CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_time_limit()`. If you want to disable timeout overall, pass it 0 as an argument. Otherwise pass it the number of seconds of max execution time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_time_limit(0)` at the start of your code: this removes the execution time limit altogether for this script. Note that it means that the script could run "forever", so put some checks in place in case it hangs.

Answer (score -1):

[set_time_limit](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)