# Is cron job right for dealing with scripts that exceed the max_execution_time?

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

I need to import a lot of products to Prestashop using XML from external API. Our **shared hosting** has `Max_Execution_Time` set to 300s. The problem is adding images to products in Prestashop is very time consuming and 300s is not enough to add all the products with images in one execution time.

My plan to deal with it is to set up a cron job that will call the script every 10 minutes or so and let the script work for limited amount of time.

**Is my approach correct or is there another, better standard for doing it?**

I couldn't find the answer to my problem anywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840711/how-to-execute-a-large-php-script

Comment: i would move hosts. CLI scripts have a max execution of unlimited, but your host may still stop them.

Comment: If you have permissions in your server but you don't want to increase this time in all the server, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693860/8542657

Comment: @IdontDownVote what should I look for If I should change the host? Are there hosting providers that allow unlimited execution time? Or do I need to set up my own host?

Comment: @idnovate I can not do it in the shared hosting I use.

Comment: @Dave Then I would save a record as a pointer in database to know the last product processed, then next time that cron is executed it will start with the next product from the last one processed. And if it's the first execution of the day, start form the first one.

Comment: @idnovate That is what I thought, Thanks.

Comment: any vps would be great, they are no more expensive than a shared host.

Comment: @IdontDownVote if you are starting a new project it's ok, but now he should migrate all the store!

Comment: @idnovate why not, moving hosts is easy, a lot easier than dealing with a poor one

Answer (score 0):

One solution is executing the script with the `php` of the console to omit the directive `max_execution_time` or `max_input_time`.

Here an example of a cron run every 5 minutes:
`*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path_of_the_script/my_script.php`

If this doesn't omit the time out, just edit your script and add this at the beginning of the file:
`#!/usr/local/bin/php`

Resulting something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

// Your script code here...
```

**PD.** This depend on the server and my path used for `php` is the most common, but there is the possibility that it is a different one, if you have doubts you will have to validate with your hosting provider.